# capture image delete event of CKEditor

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, vue.js, ckeditor

I am integrating CKEditor in my angular application. I am applying a different approach for file upload. I have a file select input, on file selection making an API call for upload which return CDN link for uploaded image. I am updating this URL to CKEditor. till this working fine.
Now, I want to handle the image removal event of CKEditor. if the user deletes or removes an image from CKEditor I want to make another API call that will delete that specific image from the server.

how can I catch the "delete" or "remove" (backspace or delete) event in CKEditor?

```js
@ViewChild('imageFileInput') public imageFileInput: ElementRef;

public config = textEditor;
public editor = cdkEditor;
public data: string;

public onContentChange({ editor }: ChangeEvent): void {
  const data = editor.getData();
}
  
public imageUpload(event): void {
  const imageFile = event.target.files[0];
  const imgData = new FormData();
  imgData.append('newsMedia', imageFile);
  
  this.fileUpload(imgData).then((res) => {
    const url = res
    const img = `<img src=${url} />`;
    this.data = this.data + img;
    
    this.imageFileInput.nativeElement.value = ''
  });
}
  
public fileUpload(file: FormData) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    this._service.upload(file).subscribe((res)=> {
      if(res.statusCode === 201) {  
        resolve(res.data)
      }
    })
  })
}
```

```html
<ckeditor
  [editor]="editor"
  [(ngModel)]="data"
  [config]="config"
  (change)="onContentChange($event)"
></ckeditor>

<input type="file" #imageFileInput accept="image/*" (change)="imageUpload($event)" />
```

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this, or figure it out yourself?

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this, or figure it out yourself?